# Angular js es6 filter list by checkbox

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have a checkbox . true false
and I have an student model

StudentModel include the function getStudentNum() that return a number 1 or 2

I want to filter the list by checkbox :
if true than filter by 1 if false filter by 2

how could I do that using models?

the model include more data that i want to show i want to show only students with number 2 or all

I am using ES6 - angular 1.6

code:

```
 <div class="item"  ng-repeat="stu in $ctrl.list track by $index | filter: stu.getStudentNum()">
</div>
```

but how can I control the list and update the view ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have your getStudentNum() function return true or false rather than the 1 or 2?

Comment: the model include more data that i want to show 

i want to show only students with number 2 or all @Chris

Comment: Have you read the documentation of filter? Have you noticed it can take a predicate function as argument? Try doing that, with a function that returns true if the student num is 1 and the checkbox is true, or when the student num is 2 and the checkbox is false. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter